# HTML div items overlap when shrinking browser window

Tags: css, html, html-lists

Why are my `<ul>` items overlapping in the first image? (When I shrink the browser window)

Everything looks fine in a full screen browser: (second image)

[image: Shrink browser and the ul items start to overlap with rest of navigation]

[image: Full screen browser OK!]

Here's what my CSS looks like:

```
.navMain {

    float:right;
    margin:-60px 0px;

}

.navMain ul {

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}

.navMain ul li {


    padding-right:80px;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navMain">

            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Most Liked</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>

</div> <!-- END navMain -->
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `float:left`

```
.navMain ul {

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

or `float:right` depending on the design.

Comment: That doesn't change anything for me. I already have `float:right` inside `.navMain` so it inherits.

Comment: please load the css in the right hand side of the box otherwise I will not be able to help.

Comment: I just updated css. You can see the window already overlapping.